# No able to spawn more than 1 enemy in java/libgdx

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, accumulator

I'm following a libGDX tutorial on how to make a running game, I'm tryng to make a random enemy spawn every 2 seconds, but what I get is just one random enemy at the beginning.

I think there is something wrong in private void update, becouse even if I remove it, the game will still spawn one single random enemy.

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);

    Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>(world.getBodyCount());
    world.getBodies();

    for (Body body : bodies) {
        update(body);
    }

    // Fixed timestep
    accumulator += delta;

    while (accumulator >= delta) {
        world.step(TIME_STEP, 6, 2);
        accumulator -= TIME_STEP;
    }

    //TODO: Implement interpolation

}

private void update(Body body) {
   if (!BodyUtils.bodyInBounds(body)) {
       if (BodyUtils.bodyIsEnemy(body)&& !runner.isHit()) {
            createEnemy();
       }
     world.destroyBody(body);
    }
}

private void createEnemy() {
    Enemy enemy = new Enemy(WorldUtils.createEnemy(world));
    addActor(enemy);
}
```

Comment: What are `world` and `accumulator`?

Comment: The world class manages all physics entities, dynamic simulation, and asynchronous queries. The world also contains efficient memory management facilities.
About the accumulator I don't know much.

Comment: ... Ok. There are no loops, runnables, theads or services, that I can see. I would suggest that is why the code is not re-running.

Comment: @doveyg If this is an Actor subclass in libgdx, the `act` method is called repeatedly in the game loop. @OP, can you show your `WorldUtils.createEnemy` method?

Comment: Check the `bodies`'s contents. Maybe printing its length will do.